# How to display the content of more then one SQL database row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html

I am trying to retrieve the data stored in an unknown number of mySQL database rows and display them using HTML. At the moment I can display data from one row.

Each row has a unique id number, I was planning to iterate through by comparing this number to the variable `counter`. But it would then leave me with the issue of displaying the results in HTML. At the moment I am just echoing variables that contain data from the rows. However what I want to create is a HTML list that increases in length depending on how many rows are in the table.

Here is my current PHP code for retrieving a row from the database is:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM project_tasks WHERE project_name='$proj_name' AND task_id='$counter'"; 
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
$row = $query->fetch_assoc();
$task_id = $row["task_id"];
$proj_name = $row["project_name"];
$task_name = $row["task_name"];
$task_importance = $row["task_importance"];
$task_description = $row["task_description"];
$task_deadline = $row["task_deadline"];
$task_members = $row["task_members"];
$task_budget = $row["task_budget"];
```

At the moment I am just displaying some of the results in HTML using this code:

```
<div id="inner_container">
            <?php echo "$task_id $proj_name $task_name $task_deadline"; ?>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM project_tasks WHERE project_name='$proj_name' AND task_id='$counter'"; 
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);

while($row = $query->mysqli_fetch_assoc()) {

  $task_id = $row["task_id"];
  $proj_name = $row["project_name"];
  $task_name = $row["task_name"];
  $task_importance = $row["task_importance"];
  $task_description = $row["task_description"];
  $task_deadline = $row["task_deadline"];
  $task_members = $row["task_members"];
  $task_budget = $row["task_budget"];

  echo "$task_id $proj_name $task_name $task_deadline";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have built an associative array using `fetch_assoc` all you need to do is loop through that array.  The OO example on http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php should get you what you need.  A quick example:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM project_tasks WHERE project_name='$proj_name' AND task_id='$counter'"; 
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);

echo '<div id="inner_container">';
    while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        $proj_name = $row["project_name"];
        $task_name = $row["task_name"];
        $task_deadline = $row["task_deadline"];

        echo "$task_id $proj_name $task_name $task_deadline";
    };

    /* free result set */
    $row->free();

echo '</div>;
```